# Отправка данных в PHP файл с помощью ссылку JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Привет всем, делаю голосование за статью, при нажатии на ссылку нужно как-то передать 2 параметра, это + или - и id поста в блоге
Прошу помочь, нужно передать 2 параметра в файл post_vote.php
Искал в интернете, читал доки, но как передать 2 параметра и как их указать в ссылке просто не понимаю

```
<a class="btn btn-small pull-right" href="#"><i class="icon-thumbs-down"></i></a> 
<a class="btn btn-small pull-right" href="#"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Добавим класс к кнопке "за" и "против" buttonVote
2. Добавим атрибут data-id, в значении которого укажем id записи. Например, data-id="2"
3. Добавим атрибут data-vote, в значении которого укажем куда (+ (вверх) или - (вниз)): например data-vote="up"
4. Обработаем нажатие на кнопку

   ```
   $('.buttonVote').live('click', function(e) { 
   e.preventDefault();
   $.get('/script.php', {id: $(this).data('id'), vote: $(this).data('vote')},    function(data) {
        //Обрабатываем ответ
   })

   });
   ```

Вместо get можно использовать post, конечно )

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live' ошибка

Comment: попробуйте тогда вместо live, bind

Comment: ну, вообще ничего не происходит, а что в обработчике писать?

Comment: что угодно. эту функцию можно и опустить. А можно хоть `alert('голос учтен')`

что в консоли пишет? есть ошибки какие?

Comment: вообще ничего

Comment: live устарело, bind используется так: 

`$('body').bind('click','.buttonVote',function(){})`

Comment: [As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<a class="btn btn-small pull-right" href="post_vote.php?vote=up&post_id=1"><i class="icon-thumbs-down"></i></a> 
<a class="btn btn-small pull-right" href="post_vote.php?vote=down&post_id=1"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i></a>

 $(".btn").click(function(){
    $.get($(this).href,function(data){
       alert(data);
    });
    return false;
 });
```

data - то что вернет скрипт post_vote.php

Comment: не работает, лишь обновляет ВСЮ страницу и в url страницы попадает http://blog/post/180/post_vote.php?vote=up&post_id=1

Comment: просто тут ошибка в коде, кажется. Могу ошибаться

 $(".btn").live("click", function(){
    $.get($(this).href,function(data){
       alert(data);
    });
    return false;
}
 );

Comment: нет, не работает Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'

Comment: Прям все используют `live()`... Никто так и не перешел на 1.9?

Comment: обновил, попробуйте

Comment: тупо обновляется вся страница и всё